# How to stop IPEndPoint.Serialize() from Garbage Collecting

Tags: c#

I am having a small issue please click image to enlarge I am now positive that the IPEndPoint.Serialize call is coming from the Socket.SendTo method. I have commented that code out of my class. Now I am stuck wondering how do you avoid that from being garbage collected?? The profiler is from Unity3d but the code should not reflect the engine as I can run the API in Visual Studio.

[image: Performance Analyzer]

```
    public static void BroadCast(Packet packet, Protocol protocol, EndPoint exemptConnection = null)
    {
        lock (Rnet)
        {
            lock (Ipo.PeerData)
            {
                if (Ipo.PeerData.Count == 0)
                {
                    Recycle(packet);
                    return;
                }

                if (packet.Flag == PacketFlags.None)
                    packet.Flag = PacketFlags.Dat;

                foreach (var i in Ipo.PeerData)
                {
                    if (i.Equals(exemptConnection)) continue;

                    if (protocol == Protocol.Sequenced)
                    {
                        packet.RemoteEp = i.Key; 
                        SetId(packet);
                        packet.Proto = protocol;
                        packet.WriteHeader();
                    }
                //The issue is in the Socket.SendTo Method I commented it out to make sure
                _socket.RnetSocket.SendTo(packet.Data.Array,packet.Data.Count, System.Net.Sockets.SocketFlags.None, i.Key);
                }

                if (packet.Proto != Protocol.ReliableOrdered)
                    Recycle(packet);
            }
        }
    }
```

This class is always recycled back into a Queue after usage so GC will not collect on it. (I have confirmed the issue is not in this class)

```
public class Packet
{
    public Protocol Proto = Protocol.Sequenced;
    public PacketFlags Flag = PacketFlags.None;
    public Fragment Fragmented = Fragment.None;
    public EndPoint RemoteEp = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, 0);
    private ushort _id;
    public ushort Lead;
    public int MssPackets;
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure i understand your problem.  Serialize makes a string.  A string should be GC'd when it's no longer being referenced.

Comment: I guess you could use some static string and lock around it as well to manage it's state, and always serialize into that string, and send that string in your send method.  But is it really a problem? The string will be quickly GC'd, it won't survive multiple generations, so it should be fine

Comment: @BrianWhite, Thank you I looked at the source and its creating a new object https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System/net/System/Net/IPEndPoint.cs,130 not sure why the socket would ask for an EndPoint only to converge it to a IPEndPoint.